# Reusable gloves for bike repairs?

Tags: maintenance, chain, lubricant, cleaning, gloves

I'm looking to [degrease](http://www.green-oil.net/Clean%20Chain%20degreaser.html)/[lube](http://www.green-oil.net/Green%20Oil%20chain%20lube.html) the chain, adjust disc brakes, clean, etc. at home, but don't want to get my hands dirty. (Zinger alert.)

Are there any special re-usable gloves for this kind of bike work?

I'm asking because the usual latex stuff won't likely last long, especially if ripped on something sharp.

Alternatively, will regular household gloves work? Or what about garden ones?

[image]

<sub>P.S. I mentioned the type of lubricant and degreaser I'm using to show that it's not corrosive and carcinogenic like the usual stuff; so in my case, I am only concerned with not getting oil and black smears all over my hands.</sub>

Comment: careful with kitchen gloves: brake/shift cables that are frayed will tear those, and plain nitrile gloves quite easily

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Park Tool](http://www.parktool.com/product/nitrile-mechanics-gloves-mg-2) recommends their own product:
[image: Park Tool Gloves]

I used to hate gloves for anything (car, bike, whatever) until I got used to wearing them while in Iraq and Afghanistan. Originally I used the [Mechanix Wear](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001VNZUA) gloves and I still like them for working on my car:

[image: Mechanix Glove]

Comment: Thanks! There's 100 in that box, so the latter seem to be more on the sweet spot for re-usability: what are they originally intended for? Repairs? (You're special forces, nice!)

Comment: They're intended for mechanics to use with cars. When the wars were spooling up they became really popular in military circles (who started the trend I have no idea, but I blame team guys). Eventually tactical equipment manufacturers and the supply system caught up with demand and started producing their own for military style. I have an awesome pair of Oakley gloves that I..errr.. "borrowed" from a supply bin at the CJSOTF.

Comment: @Baumr You'll also see people in the mountain bike community riding in Mechanix gloves. Personally, I've found them to be twice as durable as any full fingered cycling glove I've ever worn. They're all I use anymore. The ones pictured don't have padding like cycling gloves do, but you can find Mechanix gloves that do. Just hit up your local auto parts store.

Answer (score 5):

[Atlas-Fit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016MZIN0) nylon gloves are surprisingly good when you want to work in oil, rain or cold. They stretch over your fingers and are easily tough enough to put snow cables on car tires in the winter.

I know a bicycle mechanic that prefers to use these when they are doing oily work — like flooding bearings or breaking frozen parts they are soaking in oil: the gloves are not slippery when working with grease or oil. Also, a stray wire from a shifter cable is less likely to poke through them.

To keep your hands cleaner, wear nitrile gloves below them. (Also helps with other gloves in cold weather.)

[image: Atlas nylon mesh black glove]

(For most bike work, I often use disposable nitrile gloves, but I often chew right through the fingers and knuckles on those quickly.)